# My function on Go using fpdf double page resolution each time after save to pdf file

Tags: go, pdf-generation

I am not an experienced developer in Go, all that I normally do kind of small micro services for work task automation. So I have a task to update existing PDF file, add to it QR code and some comments next to it. File and comments will come from HTML form (no I use Postman for testing). It takes me some time, but finally I am figure out how to get file and string, generate arcade insert it into pdf and save it. And here I got a problem, each time when I save file into pdf it doubled page resolution. I look at Pagesize parameters during debug till the end of function where save happened it equal to original from imported file, then save and it doubled.

So if you try to add QR to generated file if will be smaller, next time even smaller and it is behave in that way till infinity. I need possibility to add several QR code step by step (by different people) to same file with same formatting.

I try to use fixed page size it does not help, try to add page without formatting it generate very strange thing.

I use go version 1.20.2 for work with PDF I use

```
"github.com/phpdave11/gofpdf"
"github.com/phpdave11/gofpdf/contrib/gofpdi"
```

the code itself you can find bellow

```
// Handling of post requests in order update pdf file
func (a *App) qrAddToFile(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    var png []byte //byte array for qrcode in png

    // here we get data from form whic is string for qr generation and pdf file where this qr need to be inserted
    r.ParseMultipartForm(4048)
    qrstring := r.FormValue("qrstring")
    png, err := qrcode.Encode(qrstring, qrcode.Medium, 256) //decode string into qr png image
    pngfile := savePngToFile(png)                           //save image to file

    file, fileHeader, err := r.FormFile("qrfile") //get pdf file from post request
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }

    defer file.Close()

    // Save pdf file under unique name
    tmpfilename := fmt.Sprintf("./%d%s", time.Now().UnixNano(), fileHeader.Filename)
    dst, err := os.Create(tmpfilename)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    defer dst.Close()

    _, err = io.Copy(dst, file)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    // start import pdf as a template
    imp := gofpdi.NewImporter()

    pdf := gofpdf.New("P", "mm", "A4", "")
    rs, _ := getTemplatePdf(tmpfilename)
    tpl := imp.ImportPageFromStream(pdf, &rs, 1, "/MediaBox")
    pageSizes := imp.GetPageSizes()
    nrPages := len(imp.GetPageSizes())
    var sizeType gofpdf.SizeType

    for i := 1; i <= nrPages; i++ {
        tpl = imp.ImportPageFromStream(pdf, &rs, i, "/MediaBox")
        sizeType.Wd = pageSizes[i]["/MediaBox"]["w"]
        sizeType.Ht = pageSizes[i]["/MediaBox"]["h"]
        pdf.AddPageFormat("P", sizeType)
        imp.UseImportedTemplate(pdf, tpl, 0, 0, sizeType.Wd, sizeType.Ht)
    }
    // import all pages from exsisting file

    pdf.AddPageFormat("P", sizeType) // add new page same format as previous
    // add qrcode on page
    rdr := bytes.NewReader(png)
    _ = pdf.RegisterImageOptionsReader(pngfile, gofpdf.ImageOptions{ImageType: "png", ReadDpi: true}, rdr)
    pdf.Image(pngfile, 10, pdf.GetY()+5, 200, 200, false, "", 0, "")
    // add some comments on left side of qr code
    tr := pdf.UnicodeTranslatorFromDescriptor("cp1251")
    pdf.AddFont("Helvetica", "", "helvetica_1251.json")
    pdf.SetFont("Helvetica", "", 27)
    pdf.SetXY(220, 10)
    pdf.SetCellMargin(2)
    pdf.MultiCell(370, 12, tr(qrstring), "1", "", false)
    err = pdf.Error()

    checkErr(err)
    err = pdf.OutputFileAndClose("QR.pdf") // save file
    checkErr(err)
}

func getTemplatePdf(fname string) (io.ReadSeeker, error) {
    file, err := os.Open(fname) // For read access.
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    readSeek := io.ReadSeeker(file)
    return readSeek, nil
}
```

I am in dead end, can anyone help me?

Best regards
Artur

Comment: After some experiments I find out that even if you do not add anything to original file, just use it as a template and then save it, original resolution will be increased x 2.83. It is kind of strange behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I find out the root of the problem, it was all about units. In my code it was
`pdf := gofpdf.New("P", "mm", "A4", "")`
all that I need to do it change it to
`pdf := gofpdf.New("P", "pt", "A4", "")`
and everything runs perfectly.